# How to make blockly horizontal

Tags: javascript, blockly, google-blockly

I want to make a block based program like scratchjr. I use blockly but I don't know how to change blocks shape/direction; I want to make blocks iconic and Horizontal, like this picture:
[image]
The Question is: How to change blocks shape and direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, that's using **[Scratch Blocks](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-blocks)**
No code needed by this way.
there are the **blockly** base with the **scratch technology**, this is the real **scratchjr**... no more, no less.